# How can I convert a Dart POST request to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

As I said, I want to convert that POST request with a file to JavaScript. This code sends a JSON request which contains an image file to server.

The Dart function is this (convert this to javascript):

```
Future postData(User user, VideoGame videoGame, File file) async {

    Map data = {
      'name': user.name,
      'contact': user.contact,
      'location': {
        'country': user.country,
        'state': user.state,
        'city': user.city
      },
      'videoGame': {
        'name': videoGame.name,
        'type': videoGame.type,
        'console': videoGame.console,
      }
    };

    try {

      String _url = baseUrl + 'insertData';

      var uri = Uri.parse(_url);
      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
        ..headers.addAll({'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Accept': 'multipart/form-data'}) 
        ..fields.addAll({'data': json.encode(data)});
      
      request.files.add(
        http.MultipartFile(
          'image',
          file.readAsBytes().asStream(),
          file.lengthSync(),
          filename: file.path.split("/").last
        ),
      );
      
      var response = await request.send();
      
      print('Status ${response.statusCode}');

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();
        print(jsonDecode(respStr));

        MyALertKey
            .currentState
            ?.setState((){});
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Video Games POST error => ${e.toString()}");
    }
  }
```

Because the server written in Python I couldn't see that this file sends to server (request full body).

I have written this in JavaScript but it doesn't work.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData()

    var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({
      name: somevalue,
      contact: somevalue,
      location: {
        country: somevalue,
        state: somevalue,
        city: somevalue
      },
      videoGame: {
        name: somevalue,
        type: somevalue,
        console: somevalue,
      }
    })],{
      type: 'application/json'
    })

    data.append('data',blob)

    data.append('image',file_from_input)


    try {
      const res = await fetch('url',{
        method:'POST',
        cache: 'default',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: data
      })
      let data_ = await res.json()
      console.log(data_)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }

    console.log(res.status) // will be 400 bad request

  }
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the JSON-encoded data into a blob?

Comment: `data.append('image',file_from_input)` - and `file_from_input` is what, exactly?

Comment: Also, you should not set the `Content-Type` header yourself here. If you set it like this, then it is missing the _boundary_, that is necessary to tell the server where it has to take the multipart request body apart into its separate elements again. Remove it, and let ferch figure it out on its own. https://muffinman.io/blog/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/

Comment: Flutter using Dart language and not JavaScript

Comment: the flutter code works well i want to convert to javscript for web

Comment: document.querySelector('myfuleinputelement').files[0] => file_from_input